# Failed to install orca via pip. "conflicting dependencies"

Tags: python, pip, plotly, orca, plotly-express

I can not install orca via pip. It returns the following error:

> ERROR: Cannot install orca==1.0.0, orca==1.1.0, orca==1.2.0,
> orca==1.3.0, orca==1.4.0, orca==1.5.1, orca==1.5.3, orca==1.5.4 and
> orca==1.6 because these package versions have conflicting
> dependencies.
>
> The conflict is caused by:
> orca 1.6 depends on tables<3.7 and >=3.1; python_version >= "3.6"
> orca 1.5.4 depends on tables<3.7 and >=3.1; python_version >= "3.6"
> orca 1.5.3 depends on tables<3.7 and >=3.1; python_version >= "3.6"
> orca 1.5.1 depends on tables>=3.1.0
> orca 1.4.0 depends on tables>=3.1.0
> orca 1.3.0 depends on tables>=3.1.0
> orca 1.2.0 depends on tables>=3.1.0
> orca 1.1.0 depends on tables>=3.1.0
> orca 1.0.0 depends on tables>=3.1.0
>
> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
>
> ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies